# having trouble understanding this recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to find the sum of integers in an array using recursion.
The following code throws an error :

```
var sum = function(array) {
    if(array.length === 0) return 0;
    while(array.length) {
        sum = array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
        return sum;
    }
}
```

while this works :

```
var sum = function(array) {
    if(array.length === 0) return 0;
    while(array.length) {
        return array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
    }
}
```

The difference is the way the sum is returned. Can someone explain?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: `sum = array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));` overrides the local function name, `sum` won't refer to the function on the second round of while loop. Or actually there won't be a second round, since you're returning from inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the while loop never loops - it executes a return statement before testing the loop condition a second time.

Even so, why does the first version work the first time it is called but not the second?

```
sum = array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
```

stores the right hand expression value in `sum`, after the function call to `sum` returns. That variable is in scope, so the assignment is valid.

But the assignment doesn't occur until after the call to `sum` (on the right hand side) returns. Each time `sum` returns, assignment overwrites the variable `sum` with the partial, and eventually the final result.

So the first call works successfully, but leaves `sum` set to the result of the first call. Since you can't call a number, it errors the second time you call it.